# Trying to execute an update query where rows are variables from TEdit

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

I have a table which has values that need to be updated. There are quite a few typos as different people have added items in the past, so I have to use `'like'` despite everything.

I created a Form with all the necessary fields that need updating. I used simple `TEdit` and a `TLabel`. The plan is that one picks a type of item from an edit box and also use a `TListBox`.

Then one adds the information to be updated into each `TEdit`.

I create an update procedure as follows:

```pascal
MyQuery1.SQL.Text := ' UPDATE TheTable SET iName = edtName.text WHERE iType like "%edtType.text%" ';
MyQuery1.SQL.Text := ' UPDATE TheTable SET iPart = edtPart.text WHERE iType like "%edtType.text%" ';
...
MyQuery.ExecSQL;
```

My problem is passing the `edtVariables` in the correct format. How does one add the `"%` before and `%"` after the `edtVariable`?

I tried `'"%'+edtPart.text+'%"'` and such like, but I've never had to do this at runtime before.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read up on Delphi's db-aware controls (see f.i. this tutorial http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/Using+Data-Aware+Controls/).  The point about db-aware controls (like TDBEdit) is that data transfer back and forth between the records in the database and the on-screen editing controls is completely automatic and renders qs like yours completely redundant.

Comment: In addition to @MartynA's comment, I don't know why you think that the database server would know what `edtName.text` would be, as that is only available in your Delphi code. Search this site for `[delphi] parambyname` for some examples of using parameterized queries.

Comment: etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/…) Cannot be reached from where I live. Do you really think that I should go though every record in a 120,000 row database to edit each incorrect entry? I don't have that much time left to live! The idea of the query was to update every incorrect record for each item group, which would still take me the best part of a day. I'm afraid this wasn't very helpful. I lost all my books on Delphi when I retired 15 years ago. I'm trying to do a favor for a friend's business (one of the few that hasn't yet gone into bankruptcy)

Answer (score 1):

Using FireDAC in a parametrized query, you use ':' in front of a parameter name:

```
MyQuery1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE TheTable SET iName = :NameText WHERE iType like :TheValue';
```

Then you set the parameter value before executing the request:

```
MyQuery1.ParamByName('TheValue').AsString := EdtType.Text;
MyQuery1.ParamByName('NameText').AsString := EdtName.Text;
MyQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: I'm not using FireDAC, I've never even looked at it. I'm old school. I solved my problem in a different way. I used HeidiSQL  Wrote my query in Notepad, updated all the rows with correct values by copying all the lines of SQL to Heidi and running the update. Use Search and Replace to change the values in Notepad and copy and paste again. I'll soon be finished. Not quite what I wanted, but being told to go back to school when you are 80 years old and trying to earn a bit of extra cash, when all your family are out of work due to the 'flu hoax, isn't quite what I had hoped for.

Comment: I shown code using FireDAC because you didn't specify which component you was using nor the Delphi version. This being said, it is the same kind of code with all component set with slight variations. You just have to look into the documentation of the component you use.

Comment: @MartynA You are always better understood when you explicitly state your opinion :-) Fixed the item I missed in my answer.

Comment: @fpiette  Ah. ok.